# Error Trying To Open A Page with Urllib. (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, urllib

Im looping through a set of pages while scraping, but a specific one keeps raising an error, this though the others work just fine.

To test the problematic page, I just wrote:

```
class AppURLopener(uReq.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"

url = 'http://snesguide.com/genre/beatemup/2'
opener = AppURLopener()


try:
    page_html = opener.open(url).read()
except:
    print("Error loading webpage")
```

`url = 'http://snesguide.com/genre/beatemup/1'` works

`url = 'http://snesguide.com/genre/beatemup/3'` works too

`url = 'http://snesguide.com/genre/beatemup/2'` raises the following:

(I should mention that all three work in a browser!)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PHIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 546, in _get_chunk_left
    chunk_left = self._read_next_chunk_size()
  File "C:\Users\PHIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 513, in _read_next_chunk_size
    return int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PHIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 563, in _readall_chunked
    chunk_left = self._get_chunk_left()
  File "C:\Users\PHIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 548, in _get_chunk_left
    raise IncompleteRead(b'')
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PHIL/Desktop/pyscripts/web-scraping/NES_DB_Scrape/scrape webpage connection test.py", line 17, in <module>
    page_html = opener.open(url).read()
  File "C:\Users\PHIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tempfile.py", line 483, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PHIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 456, in read
    return self._readall_chunked()
  File "C:\Users\PHIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 570, in _readall_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(b''.join(value))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(29049 bytes read)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: show your error message as text, an image with red letters is not legible.

Comment: It reads just fine if u click to enlarge, but fair enough, ill edit

Comment: It's because that site is broken. Server sends content up to google analytics script, than waits ~60s and sends missing closing tags. Even curl complains `== Info: transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`

Comment: So there's nothing to be done on my end to successfully scrape off of it? Definitely a bummer if so.